# c# application stops working on pc without vs 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, filenotfoundexception

So I have a c# application that runs perfect on my machine. When I try to run it on a pc without vs 2012 I get this exception at some point. I cant figure out what vs is installing that my application is referring to..

> system.io.filenotfoundexception could not load file or assembly
>   system.web.Mvc

I checked the installed drivers / programs but the program still works if I uninstall mvc 3. But if I remove vs it stops working. .net 4.5 is installed on the pc.

The application:

The application connects to a rest api and performs some post / put / get / del requests.

Comment: Make sure your pc has [.Net framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30653)

Comment: What is your C# application doing? It's very odd that it would need MVC if it's not a web app...

Comment: @Habib framework 4.5 is installed.

Comment: Key question here, is this winforms app or Web?

Comment: @T.S. Its a winforms app

Comment: Then, there is a problem. In winforms you shouldn't call anything from system.web.Mvc. I am not even sure if you can install mvc framework without VS installed because the whole point of it is to install into VS. But you can try to load MVC ddls into your app bin. To call REST you should only need System.Net.Http

Comment: Do you see Mvc in the application files list? Go to your `Project` `Properties`, select `Publish` on the left list, click `Applications Files...`. Also check the list obtained by `Prerequisites...`. How did you check if you don't have reference to that file? I advise to check in all csproj (which would uncover static references), and also in your code (to uncover dynamic loads).

Comment: @CsabaToth Yes i do! Let me try to include it and see if it works

Comment: @FlorianSchaal That (`Application Files...`) is basically the list what `Visual Studio` would package if you create an installer for your project with `Visual Studio`. So `Visual Studio` clearly senses a dependency if it is in the list. What framework do you use exactly for you REST purposes? Maybe that pulls it in. Is it maybe a debug version of a framework or development/RC/beta version?

Comment: @FlorianSchaal BTW, MVC is an Model-View-Controller framework for APS.NET (web) apps. There are MVC/MVVM frameworks for WPF and Silverlight though.

Comment: @CsabaToth I now create a installable application with publish and it works just fine now. I think a reference that i added depends on it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!:D

Comment: @FlorianSchaal I formulated an answer. But I give +1 to T.S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an installer very quickly with `Visual Studio` by going to your `Project Properties`, select `Publish` and then launching the `Publish Wizard...`. If your project really depends on `System.Web.Mvc`, it'll be included. You can also specify prerequisites throughout the wizard. The created installer can be used on machines which doesn't have Visual Studio or other developer frameworks installed.

The question still remains: what depends on `System.Web.Mvc`? If we want the answer it needs investigation of your references.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the answer is, some code in your app tries to load `System.Web.Mvc`, which shouldn't be part of Windows Forms application. `System.Web.Mvc` is installed with VS2012 and is part of the WEB development environment. Uninstalling VS2012 removes that and your app fails. The fix should consist of removing `System.Web.Mvc` from your Windows Forms application

Comment: Hhm strange, I cant find any reference to System.Web.Mvc

Comment: 2 things possible:

1- Other DLL is referenced, which is dependent on `System.Web.Mvc`;

2 - `System.Web.Mvc` loaded dynamically. Search in code files.

In both cases it could be either DLL itself or another one which is dependent on it